# Replace all instances of a string with another jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to replace all instances of a recurring string within a specific div with another using coffee script. I am not entirely sure how to do this. my HTML is:

```
<div id="post_delete_template" style="display:none">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <form data-post-id="<%= current_user.id %>" data-post-id="_id_" id="post_delete__id_" action="<%= url_for post_delete_path('_id_') %>" method="DELETE"><a href="#" id="delete_post_button">Delete</a></form>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </div>
<br />
```

Question is, in jquery(preferably coffee script notation) how do I replace all ' _id_ ' instances in my div block with lets say '99'?

Comment: `$('form').attr('data-post-id', '99')`?

Comment: A good IDE like IntelliJ will do that easily using regular expressions.

Comment: It needs to dynamically change all instances within this specific form. Basically I'm creating alot of posts and I want these posts displayed without refreshing the page. However, I need to replace the id's with the values returned from my jBuilder (json object).

Comment: If you want to destructively modify the div's content you can use the the `html` method: `var output = $('#post_delete_template').clone().html(function(_, html) { return html.replace('_id_', 99) }).html();`. That being said I would suggest using a tempating library instead, and your markup is invalid.

Comment: ^ Agree, this really looks like a job for HandlebarsJS or KnockoutJS or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

if you want just a string replace with javascript with your example try this

```
var str1 = "abcdef_id_test";
var str2 = str1.replace(/_id_/g, '99');
alert(str2);// show abcdef99test
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CLwab/)